# How to free a tree?

Tags: c, tree

One recursive function to free an entire tree.  One parameter that can take in any node from the tree.  Each node contains a pointer to parent node and children nodes.  No helper functions and no other parameters.

What I have:

```
void freeTree(Node *node)
{
  int i, j;
  Node *parent = node->parent;
  for (i = j = 0; i < node->nChild; i++) {
    if (node->child[i]) {
      j++;
      freeTree(node->child[i]);
    }
  }
  if (j != 0 && parent != NULL) {
    freeTree(parent);
  } else {
    free(node);
  }
}
```

*** Error: double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x000000000XXXXXXX ****

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were working with the root node it would be easy, just call the function recursively for all children then free the node you are on.  It's easy enough to find the root, just recursively call the function with the parent if there is one then return.  Once you reach a node with no parent, remove the parent link from all children so they are the roots of their own trees, call the function recursively for them, then free the node you are on.

```
    A
   / \
  B   C
     / \
    D   E
```

If you call the function with `D` or `E`, it will call itself for `C` and return.  If called with `B` or `C` it will call itself with `A` and return.  When called for `A` since there is no parent, it will remove the parent links from `B` and `C`, call itself for `B` and `C`, free node `A` and return.  Now that `B` doesn't have a parent, it will free itself.  Since `C` doesn't have a parent anymore it will remove the parent links from `D` and `E` then call itself for those, free node `C` and return.

```
void freeTree(Node *node)
{
    int i;

    /* find root node */
    if (node->parent) {
        freeTree(node->parent);
        return;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < node->nChild; i++) {
        node->child[i]->parent = NULL; /* no parent so will free it and children */
        freeTree(node->child[i]);
    }
    free(node);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Splitting the code in several function will make it easier to read and understand.

```
Node* findRoot(Node* node) {
    if (node->parent) {
        return findRoot(node->parent);
    }
    return node;
}

void freeNode(Node* node) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < node->nChild; i++) {
        if (node->child[i]) {
            freeTree(node->child[i]);
        }
    }
    free(node);
}

void freeTree(Node* node) {
    freeNode(findRoot(node));
}
```

Comment: it goes into an infinite loop:  freeTree(child), freeTree(parent), freeTree(child), freeTree(parent)...

Comment: Oh yeah I see what the pb is, let me update the code.

Comment: Edited with a more efficient way to do it.

Comment: I did not write the structure, and I am not allowed to edit the structure.

Comment: The new edit is probably more clear about what happens, and you also get 3 functions for the price of one.